# How to loop an ARRAY Contains object and its object property contains an array in reactJS

Tags: reactjs

Here is an **dateData** (3) [{…}, {…}, {…}] this contains three objects and each object value have its own array how to get value from that array
`0: {dateValue: Array(13)} 1: {dateValue: Array(13)} 2: {dateValue: Array(13)}`

Comment: Pls provide more information and code about what you've tried.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (const data of dateData) {
  console.log(data.dateValue);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const array = [
  { dataValue: [1, 2, 3] },
  { dataValue: [{ obj: 1 }, { obj: 2 }, { obj: 3 }] },
  { dataValue: ["test1", "test2", "test3"] },
];

array?.forEach((element) => {
  element?.dataValue?.forEach((ele) => {
    console.log(ele);
  });
});
```